# core data Group By fetch all propetries issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, ios8

I have a single table

```
DB_SMS 
----------------------------------------
contactId | messageText | to | createdAt
```

I want fetch the most recently created record for each contactId.  For example:

```
contactId | messageText | to | createdAt
        1 |       msg01 |  a | 2015-04-20
        1 |       msg02 |  b | 2015-04-21
        2 |       msg03 |  c | 2015-04-20
        3 |       msg04 |  d | 2015-04-20
        3 |       msg05 |  w | 2015-04-22
```

Required result

```
contactId | messageText | to | createdAt
        1 |       msg02 |  b | 2015-04-21
        2 |       msg03 |  c | 2015-04-20
        3 |       msg05 |  w | 2015-04-22
```

I am using following code

```
NSFetchRequest * theRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"DB_SMS"];

[theRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

[theRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"contactId",@"messageText",@"to",@"createdAt"]];

[theRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"contactId"]];

[theRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:NO]]];

NSArray * theArray = [theDbHandler.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:theRequest error:nil];
```

i'm getting following exception

```
SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions
```

plz suggest some solution .

Comment: Do you want them ordered by contactID - it does'nt make sense to use Group By on messageText column - you can't add this column up - which is what a GROUP BY clause will try and do.  Just add another sortDescriptor for the contactId then you will get a list sorted by contactId and createdAt.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald , i want to fetch records with latest created time grouped by contactId . means let say i have 3 contactId's with multiple combinations , i want to fetch only 3 records , each record with unique contactId and latest createdAt time .

Comment: Right but GROUPED BY is not the right tool for that is it?  You might have to run two queries, one to get the unique contactId and then another to get the most recent record for each contactId.  I could be wrong but I don't think you will find a way to do that in a single query with Core Data.